# What are the contents of RemoteMessage of Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

https://blog.logrocket.com/flutter-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging/

```
// For handling the received notifications
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  // Parse the message received
  PushNotification notification = PushNotification(
    title: message.notification?.title,
    body: message.notification?.body,
  );
```

As we can see, `notification` is one field in `RemoteMessage` structure.

and here: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/example

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}
```

`messageId` is another field in RemoteMessage.

What other fields are in this RemoteMessage structure? I tried to find its API but failed.

Can we override it and fill our own fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/latest/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/RemoteMessage/RemoteMessage.html) is the structure of `RemoteMessage`. You can add your custom data to the `data` property of it.

```
const RemoteMessage(
    {this.senderId,
    this.category,
    this.collapseKey,
    this.contentAvailable = false,
    this.data = const <String, dynamic>{},
    this.from,
    this.messageId,
    this.messageType,
    this.mutableContent = false,
    this.notification,
    this.sentTime,
    this.threadId,
    this.ttl});
```

A usual notification payload when send from the backend/cloud functions looks like this:

```
const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: message,
    },
    data: {
      uid,
    },
    webpush: {
      notification: {
        icon: photoURL,
      },
    },
    android: {
      notification: {
        image: photoURL,
      },
    },
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          "mutable-content": 1,
        },
      },
      fcm_options: {
        image: photoURL,
      },
    },
  };
```

Comment: Can we add custom data to notification field too?

Comment: The `notification` field has this structure: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/latest/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/RemoteNotification/RemoteNotification.html  Usualy the `data` field is for custom data. Can't you use that?

Comment: Please see this question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68175785/meaning-of-in-flutter-with-respect-to-remotemessage Here that code has access to `notification.title`. I want to know how did they get title inside `notification`?

Comment: Yes. The `title` comes from the `notification`. I see @Puff already answered that. He is the best person in the world to help you with Firebase :) we all learn and learned from him.

Comment: But where from do we put title in the notification? Can you explain that, please?

Comment: Can you show me the code where you send your notification? Or do you use only the firebase console to test it?

Comment: I haven't written that code. If you click on that link you will see the code there. I am just trying to understand what they have done.

Comment: Please point out the API documentation of Firebase. Example- Where is showSimpleNotification() API documentation?

Comment: The `showSmpleNotification()` comes from the `overlay_support` plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/overlay_support