# Meaning of `?.` in Flutter with respect to RemoteMessage

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/latest/firebase_messaging_platform_interface/RemoteMessage/RemoteMessage.html

`RemoteMessage` does have a field called `notification`.
But what does it mean when we say: `message.notification?.title`?

`?` means that the field can be null but when we say `?.title`, **does it mean that there is a `title` field in `notification` which we are trying to access**?

https://blog.logrocket.com/flutter-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging/

```
   FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // Parse the message received
      PushNotification notification = PushNotification(
        title: message.notification?.title,
        body: message.notification?.body,
      );
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Shortly - yes you are trying to access title and you know it can be null

It's null safety.
From https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety

> If you want a variable of type String to accept any string or the value null, give the variable a nullable type by adding a question mark (?) after the type name. For example, a variable of type String? can contain a string, or it can be null.

Additionally:

> If you’re sure that an expression with a nullable type isn’t null, you can use a null assertion operator (!) to make Dart treat it as non-nullable.
>
> By adding ! just after the expression, you tell Dart that the value won’t be null, and that it’s safe to assign it to a non-nullable variable.

Comment: Please point out the API documentation of Flutter. Example- Where is showSimpleNotification() API documentation?